# How to get max row in openpyxl library?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to get max row which has data from excel using openpyxl library in python
I am using Python 3.7 and `openpyxl` 2.6.1. 
Here is the code I am using:

```py
APIworkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("../../Excel/myfile.xlsx")
APISheet = APIworkbook["mybook"]
row = APISheet.max_row
print(row)
```

This is printing some random number, but I am expecting the last row which has data filled.

Comment: It's not a random number, it is the highest row number of the worksheet.

Comment: `.max_row` works. The first row after max row is the first where the whole row is made up of cells with a value of `None`. This sometimes does not match with the visual last used row because one or more of the cells between the last used row (visually) and that calculated by Openpyxl has a value. That value may be invisible example contains quotes. If a difference between the two is seen, select all the rows from last used (visibly) to last used calculated and delete (right click; delete), then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this and get max row count

```py
max_row_count = 0

APIworkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("../../Excel/myfile.xlsx")
APISheet = APIworkbook["mybook"]
for row in APISheet.rows:
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value:
            max_row_count += 1
            break

print(max_row_count)
```